# bash Call ext func in a echo

Tags: bash, function, echo, external

Been testing out external functions. Overall they seem to work as expected, except this one.

I set up colors in a extern script (mylib)

this seems to work fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
. mylib
red
echo " red text "
. mylib
white
echo " white text "
```

This isn't, not sure how it should go.  I'm looking to change colors on same line. (without all the escape coding)

```
#!/bin/bash
. mylib
red
echo "Red text  " . mylib white "  white text"
```

I tried out a few brackets and '$' ideas, but all fell short.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: By the way -- you only need to run `. mylib` *once*, as long as you put that command at the top of your script; there's no good reason to re-source it if you don't use subshells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but it's ridiculously inefficient.

```
echo "Red text $(source mylib; white) white text"
```

It would be *slightly* better to source the library only once:

```
source mylib # This only needs to be done ONCE!
echo "Red text $(white) white text"
```

---

Think about it: **Every single time** you want to change colors, you're asking the shell to do this:

- Call `fork()` to create a subshell
- In the parent shell, start reading all output emitted by the subshell
- In that subshell, read the file `mylib` and execute each line (in the former case)
- In that subshell, call the function `white`
- In the subshell, exit with the status of the last command to be run (in this case, that command being the `white` function). [Because the subshell is exiting, this means the work it did reading and parsing `mylib` is thrown away, and the next time a color change is needed, `mylib` will need to be reread and reparsed from scratch].
- In the parent shell, see that the child shell has closed; call `waitpid()` to reap it from the process table.
- In the parent shell, substitute the content read from the subshell into the `echo` command being run.

It would be much, much more efficient if running `source mylib` would set a *variable* named `white`, and you sourced `mylib` only once and thereafter included the variable by reference:

```
source mylib # this only needs to be done ONCE!
echo "Red text ${white} white text"
```

In that case, there's no subshell ever required, much less one per color change.

---

You might also wish to review [BashFAQ #37](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037) for a discussion of best practices for dealing with colors.

Comment: It's not clear why `mylib` is repeatedly sourced in the question. It should be sufficient to source it once, then call the functions as often as desired. There is still the problem of forking a subshell for each call to the function, so the recommendation to export a variable is still a good one.

Comment: @chepner: Indeed -- if we get rid of the OP's desire to embed the source command into the `echo` command, this gets less problematic.

Comment: Thanks guys! I almost like bash scripting.  It seems rather finicky, but it can do most of what I want/need so far.